# Can I automatically post something I write for one blog to my other blogs?

Tags: wordpress, blog, blogger, feeds

I write a blog at some site. When I write a new post to that site, is there a way to automatically post it to my WordPress and Blogger blogs as well?

Comment: See Also: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5557/wordpress-automatically-forward-a-post-to-another-blog for ways to do this on WordPress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use a blog client like Windows Live Writer
2. Use email to post your blog.

Answer (score 3):

You can autopost to blogger, WP and other services, if you have a blog at [Posterous](http://posterous.com). Posterous lets you autopost to several other services automatically. 
If you have a self hosted blog at WP, you can try out a few WP plugins which would let you do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

To Publish the Same Blog Post to Multiple Blogging Sites at Once, See following Article:
http://www.labnol.org/internet/blogging/post-blog-entries-to-multiple-blogging-platforms/4943/